# symlink for dbus headers

Tags: programming, c, symbolic-link, dbus

Source code for something that won't compile has the line `#include <dbus/dbus.h>`  but in real life that header file is in `/usr/include/dbus-1.0/`  Similar situation exists for the `dbus-c++` package.

Why doesn't Ubuntu provide a symlink `/usr/include/dbus` pointing to the `dbus-1.0` directory?  Is this an bug in the `dbus` package? If intended, what it the purpose?

Is it a proper fix to add a symlink myself?

(Changing the source is not practical - there are many files, and they need to match what other people have.)

**Update:**

Ok, I totally misunderstood the situation, though it still comes down to a problem I think should be solved by a symlink.  The dbus directory referred to in the `#include` statement is a deeper level directory under `/usr/include/dbus-1.0/`.  The real problem is that the file `dbus-arch-deps.h` appears to be missing, but is actually stored in the weird location `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include/dbus/` . So now, why doesn't Ubuntu provide a symlink to this in `/usr/include/dbus-1.0/dbus`, or actually store it there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

dbus include paths are meant to be retrieved by a call to

```
pkg-config dbus-1 --cflags
```

you can compile a program using dbus by

```
cc dbus-example.c -o dbus-example $(pkg-config dbus-1 --cflags)
```

or

```
make dbus-example CFLAGS+="$(pkg-config dbus-1 --cflags)"
```

dbus headers are included by the line

```
#include <dbus/dbus.h>
```

this "weird include paths" increase the flexibility towards future versions of dbus or other architectures.

Answer (score 0):

don_jones' answer seems to cover how the basic setup that will work. But it's not how it should be, there is a long development history for this.

Why? I don't have much background on this, but these what I could think of:

- About default location or symlink `/usr/include/dbus`

  The system is prepared to have multiple versions of the same library which are not compatible. It will be too difficult to debug, if can't know which version is `/usr/include/dbus`. I'm not talking about single lib, but if all lib used this method. Even with symlinks, then you have find and check all link in the `usr/include` tree, it is not practical.

  So the compilation time flags are best approach for this. However, you shouldn't set this flags yourself manually, make a look on the GNU autotools. This is [A brief introduction to the GNU Autotools](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/brief_introduction_to_gnu_autotools).
- About `dbus-arch-deps.h`

  Yes, it should be stored there in `x86_64-linux-gnu` path. As the name states, it is an architecture dependent header and you will multiple files with same name for each architecture. Starting from 12.04, Ubuntu became multiarch. (Even before 12.04, you can cross compile, different arch).

  In precise: [libdbus-1-dev:i386](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/libdbus-1-dev/filelist) `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include/dbus/dbus-arch-deps.h`

  You don't have to include that header manually but `autoconf` will take care of that.

There is other alternatives, example: cmake. This question is old, but it may open the door for anyone looking for the same thing.